# Какие данные нужно передавать на сервер при LogIn юзера через Google или Facebook?

Tags: java, android

Подскажите как правильно сделать? Вот есть сервер при обычной регистрации я упаковываю майл и пароль и отправляю на сервер, но как быть если у меня реализована регистрация через Google и Facebook? Как минимум я не могу получить пароль из этих аккаунтов... Как мне тогда отмечать юзера в БД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При регистрации через Google или Facebook вы можете получить данные от них: электронную почту, ID, имя, фамилию и прочее (в зависимости от прав, которые вы указали при Login через эти сети).

Поэтому в своей БД вы можете использовать эти данные. Самое простое это полученную электронную почту или ID.

Comment: Да ок, но как тогда быть в ситуации когда юзер сделал регистрацию через гугл или фейс а потом с другого девайса хочет подключиться к своему аккаунту просто через логин и пароль... ? Ведь у меня в базе проверка идет по логину и паролю, а в случае с регистрацией через гугл или фейс я не получу пароль следовательно как я буду проверять?

Comment: При регистрации через Гугл или Фейсбус, после того как получили почту, необходимо предлагать пользователю установить пароль. Получится таже самая регистрация через почту и пароль, только без необходимости вводить почту вручную. А потом, когда пользователь захочет зайти через почту и пароль, ему необходимо вести почту, которая была привязанная к аккаунту Гугла или Фейсбука и пароль, который он указывал при регистрации

Comment: А если не хотите предлагать установить пароль или пользователь отказался от этого, отсылать сгенерированный пароль ему на почту

Comment: Да точно... Мне кажется это хорошая идея

Comment: Вы можете украсть пароль от гугля, показав поддельный ввод логина гугля?

Comment: @Sergey что то я не понял суть вопроса...

Comment: Пользователю предлагается авторизоваться через гугль. Происходит редирект на страницу гуля, где он вводит логин, пароль, подтверждает доступ к своему аккаунту с Вашей программы. Так ведь можно вместо редиректа на гугль, показать поддедльную страницу и глупый пользователь введёт туда свой пароль от гугль. У нас будет безграничный доступ к аккаунту пользователя на гугле.

Comment: @Sergey )) Да, но это не наша цель...

Comment: @Sergey Такие махинации называются мошенничеством. Если выкладывать приложение с такой вещью, могут и забанить. Люди часто выбирают залогиниться через Гугл или Фестбук, потому что человек уже логинин и ему просто надо нажать "Согласен" (и вводить пароль и почту не надо)